# Django blog generate next/previous entries

Tags: python, django

In a blog application (which I have mostly built following a tutorial), I would like to have a next and previous post link on the single page views of the posts.  The blog app's urls.py file looks like this:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from django.views.generic import list_detail
from sandy.blog.models import Post


urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^post/(?P<slug>.*)/$', list_detail.object_detail,
    {'queryset': Post.objects.all(), 'template_object_name': 'post',},
    name="single_post"),
    url(r'^$', list_detail.object_list,
    {'queryset': Post.objects.order_by('-published'), 'template_object_name': 'post',},
    name="blog_home"),
```

)

In the single page template I would like to do something like this:

```
<p><a href="{% url single_post slug=[how would I derive it???] %}">Previous Post</a></p>
```

I have the Post object as post available in the template, so I can do something like

{% url single_post slug=post.slug %} for the current page, but would like to be able to do something like slug=post[-1].slug or whatever.  Is there a simple batteries included way to do this?

Of course there would need to be some checking (to see if there is a previous post or not), and I would need to repeat it for the 'next post' link as well.

I have been going around in circles to get this to work.  Is there a way, or am I forced to write out a full view for the page.

Comment: My problem is not deriving the previous or next post, but just to know if there is some way that this can be done from within the template, without having to write out a view for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want the [`get_next_by_FOO()`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_next_by_FOO) and `get_previous_by_FOO()` model methods.

Comment: Would I be able to use that within the template?  I'm not getting it right

Comment: You would, if you don't need to pass any arguments. If you do need to then you'll have to write a small view.